# Position relative, how to get rid of dead space?

Tags: html, css, positioning

my first question here, I am new to html/css so bear with me if this sounds too noobish of a question. I don't have any code so ill explain with words instead because the problem itself is simple but I cant figure out a solution right now.

When you position an element using position:relative; it moves from the place that it normally would have been at, to the specified coordinates, correct?

Now if you have many elements in normal flow and they take up let say 2000px of height together, and i want to position all those elements in a div [1000px x 1000px], so i move them in positions using position relative, all is fine and dandy, except that the page is still 2000px, even though I have moved the elements, how to solve this, is there 1 or more methods of achieving this.

Edit: Maybe It's confusing what i meant, Here is an example in code so you guys can see more clearly. Now i got those divs where i want them,  but under them, i guess you can say their initial position is still there and creates a scroll.

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
#one{
border: 1px green solid; 
height: 500px; 
width: 20px; 
}
#two{
 border: 1px black solid; 
height: 500px; 
width: 20px;
position: relative; top: -502px;  left: 100px; 
}
#three{
border: 1px red solid; 
height: 500px; 
width: 20px;
position: relative; top: -1004px;  left: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are all of your elements set to relative? Its really hard to determine what your issue is without seeing the code, as what your are saying can me coded in so many different ways.

Comment: you didn't say anything about the width's of those elements? also are ou stacking them all one on top of the other (ie if it were a table.. would it be only one column of multiple rows)? or could you also stack some next to one another? (ie if it were a table.. you can have multiple columns and the number of rows < number of elements)?

Comment: I second @AaronRussell.. even a theoretical question can be framed in terms of sample code.. in general.. if you ask a vague questions.. you'll get vague answers at best

Comment: Your right, sorry about that, am new here, will remember in future to add code always, edited now and added the code :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to constrain all elements within our div, you can use overflow:hidden

HTML

```
<div id="elementsinadiv">
    <div class="myelement">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="myelement">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="myelement">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="myelement">Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#elementsinadiv{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myelement{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zVmSv/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin instead:

```
.example {
    margin-top: -1000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Relative positioning in this case is needed to place element above element that it overlaps in result of shifting via negative margin. It may also be needed to use `z-index` if overlapped elements themselves are positioned relatively or absolutely.

Comment: Thanks, not quite sure that helps me though.